# Oracle SQL Query COST is coming more when its fired on view

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I am using view to fire SQL query in Oracle. Where condition contains column on which index is already created but still its running slow. If i replace the view code directly in query than result is fast. Using Explain plan i figured out when query is fired on View filter predicate is created but when it is run directly no such predicate is created which is hampering the performance severely. Any help or link will be appreciated. I am using Oracle 11 g database?

```
Select * from View1 where col1='xyz' (very slow)
select * from (Full query of View) where col1='xyz'(very fast)
```

On col1 index is created

Comment: Can you clue us in as to the exact order in which you ran the above 2 queries?  Also, what else was being run in between or at the same time?

Comment: The optimizer might not be able to push the condition into the view as this might return a different result set. Is there an aggregation or Windowed Aggregate in the view source?

Comment: These two queries were run independently on sql developer. Nothing else was run in between